# Am I overwriting computed property filter in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, filter

I am trying to create a reactive filter for an array in Vue. My starting array comes from an API call which returns `this.features` (geojson features). I am filtering on a nested array. This works -- but when I enter a search term and then backspace back out to an empty string, and enter another string, I am not filtering the original array but appear to be filtering the already-filtered array. How could I filter again on the original array from the API call?

computed property:

```
filteredFeatures() {
  if (this.searchTerm == '') {
    return this.features
  }
  // filter on nested array
  let filtered = this.features.filter(feature => {
    feature.properties.site_observations = feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
      el => JSON.stringify(el).match(this.searchTerm, 'i')
    )
    return feature.properties.site_observations.length > 0
  })
  return filtered
}
```

I have looked at [Vue filtering objects property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885873/vue-filtering-objects-property) but I cannot make that code work (it uses `Object.assign()`). Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'm seeing it yet, but I think here is the trouble: feature.properties.site_observations = feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
      el => JSON.stringify(el).match(this.searchTerm, 'i')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computed property is mutating `feature.properties.site_observations`, that's a nono. Computed properties should be read only.

```js
filteredFeatures() {
  if (this.searchTerm == '') {
    return this.features
  }
  // filter on nested array
  let filtered = this.features.filter(feature => {
    const site_observations = feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
      el => JSON.stringify(el).match(this.searchTerm, 'i')
    )
    return site_observations.length > 0
  })
  return filtered
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It was difficult for me to imagine a bunch of nested arrays as variable (`site_observations`) that could be filtered.

Answer (score 2):

It seems here is your problem:

```
 feature.properties.site_observations = feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
      el => JSON.stringify(el).match(this.searchTerm, 'i')
    )
```

Because this code filter feature and alter the proprieties of feature.properties.site_observations. Then, in the next read the value is alter. We say that your function it is not pure, because it alter the state of feature.

So, what you should do is:

```
 let anotherVariable = feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
      el => JSON.stringify(el).match(this.searchTerm, 'i')
    )
```

Therefore, on a function, avoid alter state of objects, this lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

On further checking, the above answer returns all site_observations, not just the ones that match the search. A much better solution is the following, using map to avoid overwriting the data, and the object spread operator to perform an object assign, and drilling down through the nested objects as follows:

```
filteredFeatures() {
      return this.features
        .map(feature => ({
          ...feature,
          properties: {
            site_observations: feature.properties.site_observations.filter(
              element => {
                return JSON.stringify(element).match(new RegExp(this.search, 'i'))
              }
            )
          }
        }))
        .filter(feature => feature.properties.site_observations.length)
    }
```